How can I enable support for the HMAT table?
I have access to a server and want to check its HMAT table.
However, the HMAT table is not present (the SRAT and SLIT are though).
I checked the Linux kernel config and the HMAT is enabled (CONFIG_ACPI_HMAT=y and CONFIG_ACPI=y). So probably the issue is with the hardware and firmware.
Can I enable the HMAT, and if so, how?
Here's the server spec (let me know if more information is needed):
$ uname -a
Linux node0.acpi-tinkering-0.prismgt-pg0.clemson.cloudlab.us 5.15.0-122-generic #132-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 29 13:45:52 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo dmidecode -t 2
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.3 present.

Handle 0x0200, DMI type 2, 8 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
    Product Name: 024PW1
    Version: A00
    Serial Number: .13D52G3.CNIVC001610605.

$ sudo dmidecode -t 0
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.3 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 26 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: Dell Inc.
    Version: 2.8.4
    Release Date: 06/23/2022
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 32 MB
    Characteristics:
        ISA is supported
        PCI is supported
        PNP is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        EDD is supported
        Japanese floppy for Toshiba 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
        5.25"/360 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Function key-initiated network boot is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 2.8

sudo dmidecode -t 4
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.3 present.

Handle 0x0400, DMI type 4, 48 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: CPU1
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Zen
    Manufacturer: AMD
    ID: 11 0F A0 00 FF FB 8B 17
    Signature: Family 25, Model 1, Stepping 1
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        HTT (Multi-threading)
    Version: AMD EPYC 7543 32-Core Processor                
    Voltage: 1.8 V
    External Clock: 16000 MHz
    Max Speed: 3900 MHz
    Current Speed: 2800 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: Socket SP3
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0700
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0701
    L3 Cache Handle: 0x0702
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Core Count: 32
    Core Enabled: 32
    Thread Count: 64
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable
        Multi-Core
        Hardware Thread
        Execute Protection
        Enhanced Virtualization

Handle 0x0401, DMI type 4, 48 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: CPU2
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Zen
    Manufacturer: AMD
    ID: 11 0F A0 00 FF FB 8B 17
    Signature: Family 25, Model 1, Stepping 1
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        HTT (Multi-threading)
    Version: AMD EPYC 7543 32-Core Processor                
    Voltage: 1.8 V
    External Clock: 16000 MHz
    Max Speed: 3900 MHz
    Current Speed: 2800 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: Socket SP3
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0703
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0704
    L3 Cache Handle: 0x0705
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Core Count: 32
    Core Enabled: 32
    Thread Count: 64
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable
        Multi-Core
        Hardware Thread
        Execute Protection
        Enhanced Virtualization

